# Iterate and count [String] Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to learn Haskell.
Currently I am making a function that should take a [String] and 'char' and return in how many strings this char presents.

```
count [] _ = 0
count (x:xs) v
 | elem v x = 1 + count xs
 | otherwise = 0 + count xs
```

How is it done correctly?

**!EDIT**

I get this error ::

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ a1 -> a
  Relevant bindings include
  v :: a1 (bound at prog.hs:7:14)
  xs :: [t a1] (bound at prog.hs:7:10)
  x :: t a1 (bound at prog.hs:7:8)
  count :: [t a1] -> a1 -> a (bound at prog.hs:6:1)
In the second argument of `(+)', namely `count xs'
In the expression: 1 + count xs
```

Comment: So you're trying the total number of occurrences of the character in all strings? Or the amount of strings in which the character occurs at least once?

Comment: Amount of strings in which the character occurs at least once

Comment: Alright give me a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` takes two arguments (a list and a character), but you are invoking it with only one (`xs`) in each guard. You should change your function to:

```
count [] _ = 0
count (x:xs) v
 | elem v x  = 1 + count xs v
 | otherwise = count xs v
```

Notice that I removed adding zero, because it's redundant and doesn't really make the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea. `elem` is a predicate that answers whether a list contains an element. Given that a `String` is a list of `char`, it would probably be better to just match on equality. Something like this:

```
count :: String -> Char -> Int
count "" _ = 0
count (x:xs) v
  | x == v    = 1 + count xs v
  | otherwise = count xs v
```

Your `count` function takes two arguments. In your example code, you're missing the second (the character you're searching for); hence the error.

---

**EDIT** The signature is `count :: [String] -> Char -> Int`; my mistake. In which case, you *should* use `elem` and it can be simplified to something like:

```
count :: [String] -> Char -> Int
count [] _ = 0
count (x:xs) v = c + count xs v
                 where c = if elem v x then 1 else 0
```

...you always do the `count xs v` recursive call, so you don't really need the guard.

Comment: The function takes a list of `String`s, not a single `String`.

Comment: @Kapol I didn't spot that! In which case, ignore what I said about `elem`: that's what should be used!

Comment: Yep .. just noticed it myself :D

Comment: Fixed and added a simplification

Answer (score 1):

Just for show a folding solution:

```
count :: String -> Char -> Int
count x c = foldr (\x y -> y+1 if x == c else y) s 0
```

foldr pick each element and perform the desired operation taking the result as the input for the next item, so in this case, we are initializing it to 0, and adding 1 for each element that is equal to the char passed to te function.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend defining the desired signature for count, so you'll get better errors, and a good feeling for the type system (since you're learning haskell)

```
count :: [String] -> Char -> Int
```

To make your code work these are in my mind the changes you'd need to make (untested)

```
count [] _ = 0
count (x:xs) v
 | elem v x = 1 + count xs v
 | otherwise = count xs v
```

You could also use built in functions like haskell to make your code a little more readable (less guards and lines), though I think it would make it a little worse performance wise.